# How to combine multiple Plone sites into one site?

Tags: plone

I have 3 Plone 4.1.4 sites under the same zope instance with the same Data.fs.  They handling different folders, files and plomino databases with different users(maybe with the same username). 
How could I combine them into one Plone site?

Best Regards.

zxl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zmi -> export will works very well in this case. You've to export from 2 sites and import in one site. You've to export JUST the data, the folders, files and documents I mean, not the whole plone site. For users, it is a bit complicated, you need to export data from portal_memberdata, portal_membership and user login and password from acl_users -> source_users.

For portal_memberdata data, you can go to site/portal_setup/manage_exportSteps and export it and import using the import tab. For portal_membership there's no such a step, but I think there's no data but just configs that should be the same in every portal. So the real problem is to migrate users in acl_users.

Answer (score 1):

Export and import your folders and files using Products.CSVReplicata.

Regarding the Plomino databases: first, export their design as XML (in the Design tab), and import it back into an empty database on the target site, then export their documents as XML (in the Replication tab), and import them back in the corresponding database on the target site.